# Error when creating patch in Pure Data using Lua language

Tags: audio, lua, puredata

I want to create Pure Data patches using the Lua language, so I can use these sounds inside Lua applications. For that, I'm using this code:

```
require("pd")
require("pdlua")

-- create a new Pure Data patch
patch = pd.newPatch(1, 1)

-- create an object and connect it to the output
pd.sendMessage(patch, "pd dsp 1")
pd.sendMessage(patch, "pd object [osc~ 440]")
pd.sendMessage(patch, "pd connect 0 0 1 0")

-- send a message to the object to start generating a sound
pd.sendMessage(patch, "pd message 1 0 bang")
```

Entretanto, ao executar o código eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
lua: teste.lua:2: module 'pdlua' not found:
    no field package.preload['pdlua']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/pdlua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/pdlua/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/pdlua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/pdlua/init.lua'
    no file './pdlua.lua'
    no file './pdlua/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/pdlua.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/loadall.so'
    no file './pdlua.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    teste.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

But I have the pdlua library installed on my computer (Linux Mint 20.04).
Any suggestions what's going on?

Comment: Where have you put the PD library files?

Comment: /home/my_user/Pd/externals (standard for Pd libraries)

Comment: This is a non-standard path for Lua modules.  You should modify `package.path` (or `package.cpath` depending on whether the library is written on C or Lua) prior to invoke `require`

Comment: Or just copy the module files in the current directory.

Comment: I install library on usr/local/lib/lua/5.4 and now I have this problem:


/pd.lua:22: attempt to index a nil value (global 'pd')
stack traceback:
 ./pd.lua:22: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 teste.lua:3: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?

Comment: Try `local pd = require("pd")` instead of `require("pd")`

Comment: There is Portuguese (?) in your question in between the code and the execution.

Comment: how did you install the `pdlua` external?